# How to replicate table columns

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL which has the following columns

```
date        count        day
_____       ______      _____
2015-04-01     10          1
2015-04-02     30          1
2015-04-03     90          1
2015-04-04     10          1
2015-04-05     80          1
2015-04-06     90          1
```

I want this table to be as for day 2-30.(Generate random numbers for count between 10 and 100).How to replicate the date series in PostgreSQL.Any help is appreciated

```
date        count        day
_____       ______      _____
2015-04-01     10          1
2015-04-02     30          1
2015-04-03     90          1
2015-04-04     10          1
2015-04-05     80          1
2015-04-06     90          1
2015-04-01     10          2
2015-04-02     40          2
2015-04-03     90          2
2015-04-04     10          2
2015-04-05     80          2
2015-04-06     80          2
2015-04-01     60          3
2015-04-02     30          3
2015-04-03     60          3
2015-04-04     20          3
2015-04-05     80          3
2015-04-06     90          3
```

Comment: You should search before asking a question. SO is not a do-my-work-for-me site. A quick search yielded these... Loop statements: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-loop-statements/    Date calculation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html    Random number: https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/random.php   Or if those are too complicated for you, you can simply make INSERT statements in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I am sorry I am a begginer in postgreSQL and now only learning it slowly.I know how to generate date series and integers seperately.The problem was combining both together.(cross join).Any way thanks for the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series` for this

```
select date, count, generate_series "day" from your_table t
cross join (
    select *
    from generate_series(1,30)
) t2 order by 3, 1;
```

Comment: Yup this works fine and thanks for the intro to cross join which I did not know earlier :)